# Are there more examples of functional equations which are also valid for the identity map?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, big-list

I find the co-incidence of the identity: $$\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B) = \sin^2 A - \sin^2 B$$ very pleasing. So, I was wondering if there are more of these type of identities.

To make my question precise: **Are there more examples of functional equations which are also valid for the identity map?**

For example, the identity map and the $\sin$ function satisfies $$(f(A) + f(B))(f(A) - f(B)) = f(A)^2 - f(B)^2.$$

Thanks

Comment: I don't get how $\sin$ 'preserves' the identity in this example. Can you define 'preserve'?

Comment: I believe it means "treat the function as if it were a homomorphism ", so you start with $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2 - B^2$, apply $f$ to both sides, to get $f((A+B)(A-B)) = f(A^2 - B^2)$, and then apply homomorphism properties to get $f((A+B)) f((A-B)) = f^2(A) - f^2(B)$. It's not clear why you don't expand $f(A+B)$ into $f(A) + f(B)$ at this point, but perhaps the rule is "apply homomorphism rules to each parenthesized or isolated term." I personally don't find this all that compelling.

Comment: @John The part you find uncompelling is what bugs me too. You either do it every time or you don't do it any time.

Comment: Well, $\sin$ is not a homomorphism, and $\sin (A^2) \neq \sin^2 (A)$ (which stands for $(\sin A)^2$), and the OP explicitly excludes homomorphisms as trivial, so... yeah it's not clear what "preserve" means.

Comment: I read the question as: "Are there more examples of functional equations which are also valid for the identity map?" (with the understanding that said validity is equivalent to a polynomial identity.) @GitGud

Comment: I think Semiclassical is more accurate than me. Can I edit my post and copy Semiclassicals version?  Or is editing the question frowned upon?

Comment: @Isomorphism: Feel free to edit the question (you can mention Semiclassical in your edit) -- improving the question to make it clearer (and answerable) is very much encouraged, not frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of arithmetic functions (i.e. functions whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$) there is the class of [*completely multiplicative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function) functions which satisfy $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all positive integers $a$,$b$. Any monomial $x^k$ is an example, but analytic number theory contains examples (Dirichlet characters, for instance) which are far less trivial.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I knew this one though. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: I'll confess, I'm sort of surprised that I can't think of other real-valued examples. (I'd hoped for something from elliptic functions, but no good) @Isomorphism